# Implementation of a direct solver in Fortran 90?

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix

My question may be elementary, but it is quite essential as I am getting confused.
Here I am supposed to solve the following equation:

$Ax=B$

From my understanding I have options of using either direct solvers or iterative solvers. I have tried using iterative solver GMRES(It is quite simple in terms of implementation on Fortran 90) but now I would like to use a direct solver for certain reasons and from resources and reviews I have shortlisted three of them:

1. UMFPACK
2. SUPERLU
3. MUMPS

I think the first two are developed using C and could be called from Fortran 90; The third one is in Fortran 90.

Now, my question is how do I implement this or call function from my Fortran 90 code, ie. is there a reliable procedure to install or call the libraries?

There looks to be tons of literature beyond my scope of understanding.

To simplify, I have a sparse symmetric matrix $A$ , stored in skyline format and rhs vector $B$, how do I calculate $x$ using one of the direct sparse solvers in Fortran 90?

Comment: Use PETSc, i.e., write your Fortran 95 code using PETSc (should not take more than a few lines) which can then call UMFPACK/SuperLU/MUMPS.

Comment: I would suggest considering CHOLMOD (if your matrix is pos. def.) instead of UMFPACK (LU factorization is in general useful only for nonsymmetric matrices). Same applies to SuperLU.

Comment: @stali PETSc recommends only linux and I doubt its simplicity.

Comment: PETSc has the big advantage that you can switch between lots of different solvers and preconditioners once it is setup. Besides, using any other code is probably as complex as using PETSc, since you only need a small fraction of it for accomplishing your task. If nothing else is stated, it is also assumed you are using a unix-like system. So if you use an (in the context of scientific computing) exotic OS, then you should clarify your question.

Comment: if you have access to the intel MKL library: PARDISO provides a direct solver for sparse matrices using a factorisation of the matrix after fill-reducing ordering

Comment: Is it possible to install PETSc on windows with gfortran implementation?